# Minimize a window in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, resize, minimize

How do you minimize a window programmatically when using windows `WPF`? I can seem to find a .Resize attribute?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

set `WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;`

Answer (score 26):

You are looking for the [`Window.WindowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstate%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property. It is a dependancy property and when changed will set the [`Window.RestoreBounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.restorebounds(v=VS.100).aspx) property , so you can always restore to the size before the change.

See the enumeration [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.windowstate%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

```
myWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```

Answer (score 21):

```
this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```

Answer (score 21):

For those who had the same problem: keep in mind that if `ShowInTaskbar` is set to false, then `WindowState.Minimized` minimizes the Window into a small window title bar at the bottom left of the desktop - so it's not really minimized.

A workaround is to set `ShowInTaskbar` to true, set `WindowState` to `Minimized` and then reset the `ShowInTaskbar` to its old value.

Comment: This helped a lot! It is actually even better to switch the `ShowInTaskbar` from true to false whenever the `WindowState` changes to `WindowState.Minimized`. That way, when the user clicks the minimize button of the window it will also vanish completely and when the window is shown it appears in the taskbar which is probably what users expect.

Answer (score 5):

Use the window's object [WindowState property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstate.aspx) to programmaticly minimise a window.

```
window.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```

Setting window state to WindowState.Normal will *restore* the window to it's previous WindowsState, size and location.

```
window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
```

Window.Normal is a bit of a misnomer. The remarks in the [WindowState property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstate.aspx) and the [WindowState Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.windowstate.aspx) MSDN articles hint at WindowState.Normal actual functionality and testing confirms it.

Answer (score 4):

This works just fine for me.

`Application.Current.Windows[0].WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;`

Answer (score 2):

```
YourWindowName.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```

Answer (score 0):

As many said,

window.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized

will minimize the window for you.
But be careful about timing - I accidentally set this in a `MouseLeftButtonDown` handler (vs `MouseLeftButtonUp`), and the window would not restore.