# Minimize application just like in Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, window, minimize

How do you make a WPF C# application minimize like Windows 7, when the user presses the minimize button?

**Edit**

Createde a button that could do this:

```
WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```

But it minimize instantly and not shrinking to taskbar like when you minimize a folder in windows 7

Comment: The question is, what have you done to your app to stop the default behaviour working?

Comment: You mean you want to minimise the window programmatically, just like happens when the user presses the button, or?

Comment: Well, applications always minimize when the user presses the minimize button, so you shouldn't have to do anything.

Comment: Or do you mean you want to simulate this behaviour on an older version of Windows?

Comment: I've made a custom minimize button which does as edited. When the button is pressed, it minimize to taskbar instantly and not like the behavior as a normal windows application which shrinks to the taskbar

Comment: @AirTrickz So does your edit answer the question?

Comment: Are you wanting to minimise to System Tray or Taskbar?

Comment: I want to minimize to taskbar, the button i've created does the trick, men it does it instantly and not like in windows 7 where you press the minimize button and it shrinks to the taskbar

Answer (score 0):

It will happen by default if you haven't played with the window properties too much in the designer or XAML. So if you haven't changed anything, you don't actually need to do anything to get this to work - assuming you are at least displaying the stuff in a window.

To resize a WPF window in code, please refer to this question:

[Minimize a window in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841258/minimise-a-window-in-wpf)