# Minimizing Form Before Taking Snapshot

Tags: c#, wpf

Can anyone tell me how to minimize our form before taking a screen shot. I'm setting `minimizebox=true;`
but the form disappears on doing so. I want it to be visible in the task bar..

Comment: Look at the answer to this more general question (more general meaning _I want to minimize a window when I want to, that is not the main subject of the question_: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841258/minimize-a-window-in-wpf Please try googling the question before asking it here.

Comment: Have you tried setting `WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;` on your window?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the windowState to Minimize.

```
window.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```

Answer (score 0):

you must set the Windows state

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Comment: yes, I have tried this.  but when i compile it i cant see the form again. i want it to be visible down at the taskbar..

Comment: It's almost that, but it's not exactly that... I'm afraid you didn't read the tag carefully. The question is related to **WPF** not `WinForms`.

Comment: look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27599/Minimize-window-to-system-tray and here: http://alperguc.blogspot.de/2008/11/c-system-tray-minimize-to-tray-with.html